# elasticsearch MUST vs. MUST_NOT (inverse) differences

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have a fairly large `terms` aggregated results that are loaded into a dropdown list to provide a `filter` feature.

Lets say, my dropdown list has a more than 4000 animals. My another dropdown list has 4 animal colors.

Example,

`animal --> ["dog", "cat", "rabbit", ........ , "squirrel"]`

`color --> ["black", "white", "grey", "brown"]`

The documents in `elasticseatch` looks like this:

```
{"animal": "dog", "color": "white"},
....
{"animal": "cat", "color": "white"},
....
{"animal": "rabbit", "color": "grey"},
....
{"animal": "squirrel", "color": "brown"}
```

By default, all of the `checkboxes` inside my dropdown lists are `checked` and Elasticsearch returns all results it contains. Now, I would like to see cardinality results of another field `animal_features` based on the selected animal color. This could be actually easily done if nothing were `checked` on my drop down list and I could just run the following query. The query would return the expected cardinality result for when color=black.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
              {"match": { "color": "black"}}
            ]
        }

    },
    "aggs": {
    "unique_animal_features": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "animal_features",
        "precision_threshold" : 40000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I have all the animals and colors `checked` by default. Let's say I still want the cardinality results when color=black. So in my case, I need to go ahead and uncheck every color other than black. So I go ahead and uncheck on white, grey and brown.

From second query below, I am expecting that the Elasticsearch will return me the same result since I am excluding other colors that are not black from the results using the `must_not` query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "white"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "grey"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "brown"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_animal_features": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "animal_features",
        "precision_threshold" : 40000
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

However, the second query returns a largely inaccurate cardinality result. I need to use the second query but need the results just like from the first query, how can I optimize my second query to just do that?

Note: The only difference between the first and the second query is that in case of the first query nothing is selected other than a single color. However, in the case of the second query everything including animals as well as colors are selected by default until the user starts to uncheck the colors.

Comment: There are only 4 colours or more?

Comment: @hatim Only 4 colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. In my case, there were `null` values in elasticsearch where the second query returns cardinality counts based on selected `animal` and the records containing `null` as well.

I added `"null_value": "_null_"` to my index template and I get the correct values now with the following query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "_null_"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "white"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "grey"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "brown"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_animal_features": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "animal_features",
        "precision_threshold" : 40000
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```